# changing front end results after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like some criticism about this function.  Basically  inside the function there is an ajax call, It doesn't look like you can do $(this) type deal inside ajax scope itself so I figured do it after ajax goes through with a success and change the DOM right after.

Is this a good idea?

```
$('.lock').click(function() {
    ID = $(this).closest('tr').find('a').attr('href').match(/id=(.*)/);

    check = $(this).attr('class');

    if (check.match('fa-lock')) {
        value = 1;
    } else {
        value = 0;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/assets/php/userStatus.php',
        data: 'status='+value+'&ID='+ID[1],
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(data){
            alert(data);
            location.reload();
        }
    ); //END OF AJAX

    if (value == 1) {
        $(this).attr('class', 'fa fa-unlock fa-lg lock');
        $(this).parent().prev().children('i').attr('class', 'fa fa-check fa-lg');
        $(this).parent().prev().children('i').attr('style', 'color: green;');

    } else {
        $(this).attr('class', 'fa fa-lock fa-lg lock');
        $(this).parent().prev().children('i').attr('class', 'fa fa-times fa-lg');
        $(this).parent().prev().children('i').attr('style', 'color: red;');

        // class="fa fa-times fa-lg" style="color: red;"
    }
```

});

Comment: The lines after `// END OF AJAX` are the DOM modifications you mentioned?

Comment: yes they are what will happen

Comment: That is not going to work as you expect. `$.ajax()` (or any XHR, really) is an [asynchronous call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700330.aspx), which means it will pretty much run at the soonest when synchronous code has finished executing. That is, in your example, you currently do a checking with an `if` clause, _initiate_ an AJAX request, process DOM modifications, and _then_ wait for the ajax request to complete, which will then execute synchronous code in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) inside your `success` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to work with data that hasn't been received yet....so unfortunately the whole approach is flawed.

You can cache `this` in variable before `$.ajax` and use that variable inside the success callback.

General outline:

```
$('.lock').click(function(){
      var $lock = $(this);// cache $(this);
      $.ajax({
          .......

           success:function(data){
                 // now have element inside success
                 $lock.doSomething();

           }

      });
});
```

Comment: this works fine and I have been using this method ever since